# Qt c++ compilation/linking on mac os x

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc, makefile

I need to write some code for an application that uses a camera with Ethernet connection. The company who made the camera has provided include files to read images from the camera. The files are : ImageLib.h , PvApi.h and PvRegIo.h and some library files libImagelib.a and libPvAPI.a and libPvAPI.dylib libPvJNI.dylib
I put the librarie files in `/opt/local/lib/`. I put the include files in `/opt/local/include/`

In the other hand, company provided some *.cpp examples that contains makefile for compilation. I compiled some examples and they worked perfectly. 
Now, I decide to compile one example provided by the company to list the connected cameras called ListCameras.cpp.
I create a new project on QT and just I copied the code of ListCameras.cpp.
My ListCameras.pro is like this:c

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET    = ListCameras
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH+=-l/opt/local/include/
LIBS+=-L/opt/local/lib/
LIBS+= -lPvAPI
LIBS+= -lPvJNI
DEFINES += _x64 _OSX
```

Unfortunately, I got these build errors:

```
15:56:02: Running steps for project ListCameras...
15:56:02: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
clang++ -c -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -std=c++0x -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -fPIE -D_x64 -D_OSX -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../5.0.2/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../ListCameras -I-l/opt/local/include/ -I../../5.0.2/clang_64/include -I../../5.0.2/clang_64/include/QtCore -I../../5.0.2/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I. -o main.o ../ListCameras/main.cpp
../ListCameras/main.cpp:79:51: warning: unused parameter 'junk' [-Wunused-parameter]
void SetConsoleCtrlHandler(void (*func)(int), int junk)
                                                  ^
../ListCameras/main.cpp:89:23: warning: unused parameter 'Signo' [-Wunused-parameter]
void CtrlCHandler(int Signo)
                      ^
../ListCameras/main.cpp:140:57: warning: flag ' ' results in undefined behavior with 'u' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
                        printf("%s - %8s - Unique ID = % 8lu IP@ = %15s [%s]\n",cameraList[i].SerialString,
                                                       ~^~~~
../ListCameras/main.cpp:147:57: warning: flag ' ' results in undefined behavior with 'u' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
                        printf("%s - %8s - Unique ID = % 8lu (unavailable, %u)\n",cameraList[i].SerialString,
                                                       ~^~~~
../ListCameras/main.cpp:152:53: warning: flag ' ' results in undefined behavior with 'u' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
                    printf("%s - %8s - Unique ID = % 8lu (*)\n",cameraList[i].SerialString,
                                                   ~^~~~
../ListCameras/main.cpp:171:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
             ^
../ListCameras/main.cpp:171:26: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
                         ^
clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o ListCameras main.o   -L/opt/local/lib/ -lPvAPI -lPvJNI -F/Users/rafikgouiaa/Qt//5.0.2/clang_64/lib -framework QtCore 
7 warnings generated.
15:56:02: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
15:56:02: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:56:02: Could not start process "" 
Error while building/deploying project ListCameras (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.2 clang 64bit)
When executing step 'Custom Process Step'
15:56:02: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

It looks like that it lacks some libraries or flags! Any help please?

---

error

```
  dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib//libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, it seems that you need a copy of `libjpeg`. You need to do two things:

1. Add `LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib -ljpeg` to the .pro file.
2. Install macports and, on the command line, do `sudo port install jpeg` to install the jpeg library.

Hopefully this solves this particular issue.

Comment: I check the configuraion field, it contains ListCameras (it is my current project). In the debug/Release i choose debug. But deployment field contains Deploy locally. But I got the same errors

Comment: @phdstudent Below Deployment there's Run. Make sure that the executable seems correct, etc.

Comment: Run configuration field contains ListCameras. I think there is a linker problem. May be i have to add some flags in the ListCameras.pro

Comment: "I think there is a linker problem." Not at all. "The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally." Your problem is **here**: "Error [...] When executing step 'Custom Process Step'". Get rid of that custom process step in build or deployment, and you'll be golden. Do **not** "add some flags in the project file". You have to understand the problem first *before* you attempt any solutions. Randomly "adding something" will almost never work, and will lead to project files full of cargo cult junk that's unnecessary.

Comment: In the "Build Steps" heading under Projects->tab->Build&Run->Build, you can have a "Custom Process Step". It's likely unnecessary. Basically, all you have to do to get rid of it is to exit Qt Creator and remove the `*.user` and `*.user.*` files in the project's folder. Then you'll reconfigure the project and that should clear it , I hope.

Comment: I did a new copy for my project but I get a library problem when I do execute my project.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting answers about your build, which you need to resolve. You are also getting some warnings from the compilation step, several of which can be safely ignored, but **the ones describing undefined behavior should be investigated**.